# Why I'm getting the ORA-01003: no statement parsed error?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

Why am I getting this error and what does it mean by no statement parsed.

```
 ORA-01003: no statement parsed
```

Here is the code:

```
PROCEDURE ORIGINAL_TABLE.UPDATE_GROUPS   IS
-- cursor loaded with the swam groups
CURSOR cursor1 IS
    SELECT ID, NEW_DESCRIPTION
    FROM NEW_TABLE.NEW_GROUP_TABLE@DB_LINK.X;

BEGIN
    FOR C1_REC IN cursor1 LOOP
        UPDATE
            ORIGINAL_TABLE."GROUPS"
        SET
            GROUP_ID = C1_REC.ID
        WHERE
            ORIGINAL_TABLE."GROUPS".DESCRIPTION = C1_REC.NEW_DESCRIPTION;

        IF (SQL%ROWCOUNT = 0) THEN
           INSERT INTO
                  ORIGINAL_TABLE.GROUPS("GROUP_ID", "DESCRIPTION")
           VALUES (C1_REC.ID, C1_REC.NEW_DESCRIPTION);
        END IF;

    END LOOP;

    EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
         dbms_output.put_line(SQLERRM);
END;
```

What I try to do with the code above is to update and old table with the values from a new table and in case that the new group doesn't exist insert it.

Update: Changed %ROWCOUNT > 0 for %ROWCOUNT = 0

Comment: Have you tested cursor query in another window? I think it because of query

Comment: Is this when you compile the procedure or when you execute it? Do you get a line? Maybe you need to remove the exception for a test. What also confuses me is why do you do the insert when `SQL%ROWCOUNT`is > 0 shouldn't that be = 0? But that is not your problem. And yes, does the select work as a single statement?

Comment: yes the select works as a single statement, it happens when I execute the procedure. It compile without errors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use MERGE statement, it does update/insert stuff more efficiently and pay attention your plsql doesn't provide it is intended for. It tries to make an update statement and if a record found it inserts another record. In order to fix it use 
    IF (SQL%ROWCOUNT = 0)
I presume the reason of the issue is the . in DBLINK name.

Moreover I would suggest to get rid of quotes for tables/fields just in case as well as schema name.

Another words delete all ORIGINAL_TABLE.

```
merge into groups g
using (
SELECT ID, NEW_DESCRIPTION
FROM NEW_TABLE.NEW_GROUP_TABLE@DB_LINK.X
) nt
on (nt.NEW_DESCRIPTION = g.description  )
when matched then update set g.group_id = nt.id
when non matched then insert(GROUP_ID, DESCRIPTION)
                      values(nt.id, nt.NEW_DESCRIPTION)
```

Comment: yes, about ORIGINAL_TABLE I changed the original table name to that for posting it here.

Comment: When does the block fail? either on update or insert statement? Comment both of them replacing by NULL; If it doesn't help lets continue

Comment: Try something like create table test as select * from NEW_TABLE.NEW_GROUP_TABLE@DB_LINK.X and ensure it contains values. If it doesn't we have dblink problems else try to replace the table in the cursor by newly created table 'test'. If the block fails even dealing with 'test' table it's weird.

Comment: I guess it's weird then :( the dblink statement returns the spected data when I run it alone.

Comment: Have you got 'TEST' table using the statement as I advised?

Comment: Yes, I got another table in the same database (avoiding using DBLink) that has the same information, the Test table that you say but I got the same error.

Comment: Let's remove the reason of the issue sequentially. If we comment if insert endif statement do we continue to get the error?

Comment: p.s. try to use for c1_rec in SELECT ID, NEW_DESCRIPTION
    FROM NEW_TABLE.NEW_GROUP_TABLE@DB_LINK.X loop end loop with explicit cursor. On first glance it is strange decision but may be it will help.

Comment: I deleted the if statement and the result it's the same, as well use the explicit cursor with no luck, still getting parsed error.

Comment: delete UPDATE statement as well. If the issue doesn't disappear the problem is located in iteration by remote cursor and only one way is possible - to deal with static copy of NEW_TABLE.NEW_GROUP_TABLE@DB_LINK.X prepopulated as CTAS (create table as select) before your procedure execution. p.s. as I told before - try merge statement and good luck.

Comment: I hate this... By having this troubleshooting I started convincing my self that the procedure was ok. So I thought what else could be wrong? Of course, some bug in the SQL Mananger, I've restarted the app and it works now. I'll accept the answer you give me for your cooperation, with out it I'll still be thinking that something else it's wrong. Regards

Comment: Try MERGE statement - I posted it in my answer.

Comment: Any way I'll take your recomendation about the marge statement. cheers